# improvement in my linklist program

Tags: c

Here is a program it is working

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next, *prev;
};
struct node *root = NULL;
void push(int);
void pop(void);
struct node *create_node(int);
void travel(void);
int main()
{
    int i, j, choice, count;
    printf("enter choice\n");
    scanf("%d", &choice);
    count = 0;
    while (choice == 1) {
        printf("enter a data element");
        scanf("%d", &j);
        if (count == 0) {
            root = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
            root->next = NULL;
            root->data = j;
        } else
            push(j);
        count++;
        printf("enter choice\n");
        scanf("%d", &choice);
    }
    printf("the link list is \n");
//travel function to be created
    travel();
}

void push(int data)
{
    struct node *t1;
    t1 = root;
    while (t1->next != NULL) {
        t1 = t1->next;
    }
    t1->next = create_node(data);
}

void pop()
{
}

void travel(void)
{
    struct node *t1;
    t1 = root;
    while (t1->next != NULL) {
        printf("%d ", t1->data);
        t1 = t1->next;
    }
    printf("%d ", t1->data);
}

struct node *create_node(int data)
{
    struct node *p = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    p->data = data;
    p->next = NULL;
    p->prev = NULL;
    return p;
}
```

the above program is fully working,I have used a global pointer root.
My problem is if I do not want to use a global pointer root here then how do I maintain 
that list because each time I will have to return the root of list in my push pop functions 
is there any other way to achieve the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to achieve this is to pass a pointer to the root node pointer to each of your functions:

```
void push(struct node **root, int data) { ... }
void pop(struct node **root) { ... }
void travel(struct node *root) { ... }
```

So, in your main function you might declare a local variable to hold the root pointer:

```
struct node *root = NULL;
```

and then when you call `push`, for example, you pass the address of the root poiner:

```
push(&root, data);
```

I strongly recommend that you fix your `push` and `travel` functions so that they are robust to the root pointer being `NULL`. This was discussed in a previous question of yours and you should heed the advice.

If you did that then you could get rid of the test for `count` being zero and the associated special case code. You would then replace this:

```
if (count == 0) {
    root = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    root->next = NULL;
    root->data = j;
} else
    push(&root, j);
```

with this:

```
push(&root, j);
```

To drive home the message, your new `push` would look like this:

```
void push(struct node **root, int data)
{
    if (*root == NULL)
        *root = create_node(data);
    else
    {
        struct node *last = *root;
        while (last->next != NULL) {
            last = last->next;
        }
        last->next = create_node(data);
    }
}
```

You would need to modify `travel` also to include a check for the `root` node being `NULL`. I will leave that as an exercise for you.

Maintaining both head and tail pointers could be a better approach since it would avoid so many list traversals.